# Linkedin API Postman error "INVALID_VERSION"

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I am trying to connect to the linkedin API using PostMan and I get the following error:

{
"status": 400,
"code": "INVALID_VERSION",
"message": "API versions should have date format as YYYYMM or YYYYMM.RR where RR is the revision"
}

Any ideas why?

I tried looking online but could not find an answer.